# Why mysqli_connect is not working (failing line of code included)?

Tags: php, apache, mysqli, mariadb, synology

Any idea why this isn't working?
jm-svr is the local DNS name of the Synology box Apache 2.4 server. I have swapped out the DNS name for localhost and for the IP address

```
$DB = mysqli_connect("jm-svr", "UserName_Here", "Password_Here", "DB_Name_Here");
```

DB server MariaDB10.3.21.0063

PHP error message: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047204/how-to-prevent-catch-connection-error-with-mysqli it might help in checking for errors (if any).

Comment: What error message are you getting? How do you know this is not working? Do you even have error reporting enabled? [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: @Dharman Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Comment: Solved, needed to enable MySql plugin for php in Synology WebStation